# Magento same page URL on different stores

Tags: module, magento-1, multistore, store-view

I've installed Magento Fishpig module for Wordpress integration.

I have two stores and a common blog. The only problem is that every time I accessed the blog page, the first store's layout is displayed. Any (simple) idea about how can I make it to remember the store from where the blog page is being accessed?

Comment: What happens when you pass the store code for the second store in the URL? e.g.: www.mysite.com/blog/?___store=secondstore   << take note, that's 3 underscore characters.

Comment: That's the solution. I thought there are other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access the blog via the following url string:

`www.mysite.com/blog/?___store=secondstore`

Take note, that's 3 underscores. This could potentially be coded into the index.php in the /blog/ with something like:

`$_GET['___store'] = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();`